# How to embed a graphics panel into a c# winform and maintain scalability

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Using the technique outlined in this posting:

http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/11/scale-a-drawing-so-it-fits-a-target-area-in-c/

I have produced a graphics grid intended for use as a 2D plotter.  The Winform has a panel contained within it that contains the graphics which are redrawn when the main form is resized.  No problem so far.  However, as soon as I try to add a MenuStrip, ToolStrip(s), and StatusStrip, these partially obscure the panel graphics.  Is there a way to work around this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WhatsWithPanels
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode =
                   System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            RectangleF grid_rect = new RectangleF(-1, -1, 2, 2);
            float wid = (this.ClientSize.Width - 1) / 2;
            float hgt = (this.ClientSize.Height - 1) / 2.2f;

            MapDrawing(e.Graphics, grid_rect, new RectangleF(0, 0, wid, hgt), true);   // true makes drawing stretch to fit
            DrawGrid(e.Graphics);

        }


        // Map a drawing coordinate rectangle to a graphics object rectangle.
        private void MapDrawing(Graphics gr, RectangleF drawing_rect, RectangleF target_rect, bool stretch)
        {
            gr.ResetTransform();

            // Center the drawing area at the origin.
            float drawing_cx = (drawing_rect.Left + drawing_rect.Right) / 2;
            float drawing_cy = (drawing_rect.Top + drawing_rect.Bottom) / 2;
            gr.TranslateTransform(-drawing_cx, -drawing_cy);

            // Scale.
            // Get scale factors for both directions.
            float scale_x = target_rect.Width / drawing_rect.Width;
            float scale_y = target_rect.Height / drawing_rect.Height;
            if (!stretch)
            {
                // To preserve the aspect ratio, use the smaller scale factor.
                scale_x = Math.Min(scale_x, scale_y);
                scale_y = scale_x;
            }

            if ((target_rect.Width < 1) || (target_rect.Height < 1)) return;  // avoid minimize crash
            gr.ScaleTransform(scale_x, scale_y,
                System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append);

            // Translate to center over the drawing area.
            float graphics_cx = (target_rect.Left + target_rect.Right) / 2;
            float graphics_cy = (target_rect.Top + target_rect.Bottom) / 2;
            gr.TranslateTransform(graphics_cx, graphics_cy,
                System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append);
        }


        // Draw a grid in the area(-1, -1)-(1, 1).
        private void DrawGrid(Graphics gr)
        {
            using (Pen thin_pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 0))
            {
                // draw the grid rectangle
                float x = -0.60f;
                float y = -0.60f;
                float wid = 3.3f;
                float hgt = 3.3f;

                //gr.DrawRectangle(thin_pen, -0.75f, -0.75f, 3.5f, 3.5f);
                gr.DrawRectangle(thin_pen, x, y, wid, hgt);

                Pen dashPen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 0);
                dashPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

                // draw horizontal dashed grid lines
                float x1 = x;
                float x2 = x + wid;
                float y1 = y;
                float y2 = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    gr.DrawLine(dashPen, x1, y1, x2, y1);
                    y1 += hgt / 10;
                }

                // draw vertical dashed grid lines
                x1 = x;
                x2 = -0.55f;
                y1 = y;
                y2 = y + hgt;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    gr.DrawLine(dashPen, x1, y1, x1, y2);
                    x1 += wid / 10;
                }

                // draw abcissa ticks
                x1 = x + 0.065f;
                for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
                {
                    if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) gr.DrawLine(thin_pen, x1, y2, x1, y2 + 0.10f);
                    else gr.DrawLine(thin_pen, x1, y2, x1, y2 + 0.05f);
                    x1 += wid / 50f;
                }

                // draw left ordinate ticks
                x1 = x - 0.05f;
                x2 = x;
                y1 = y + 0.065f;
                y2 = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
                {
                    if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) gr.DrawLine(thin_pen, x1 - 0.05f, y1, x2, y1);
                    else gr.DrawLine(thin_pen, x1, y1, x2, y1);
                    y1 += hgt / 50f;
                }

                // draw right ordinate ticks
                x1 = x + wid; // x - 0.05f;
                x2 = x1 + 0.05f;
                y1 = y + 0.065f;
                y2 = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
                {
                    if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) gr.DrawLine(thin_pen, x1, y1, x2 + 0.05f, y1);
                    else gr.DrawLine(thin_pen, x1, y1, x2, y1);
                    y1 += hgt / 50f;
                }

                // draw abcissa value labels
                FontFamily ff = new FontFamily("Arial");
                Font font = new Font(ff, 0.05f, FontStyle.Regular);
                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
                x = -0.70f;
                double dval = 0.0;
                string s = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    s = String.Format("{0:0.0}", dval);
                    if (i == 0) s = String.Format("  {0:0}", dval);
                    gr.DrawString(s, font, brush, x, 2.85f);
                    x += 0.33f;
                    dval += 10.0;
                }

                // draw right axis value labels
                x =  wid - 0.50f;
                y = y - 0.06f;
                dval = 100.0;
                s = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    s = String.Format("{0:0.0}", dval);
                    if (i == 10) s = String.Format("{0:0}", dval);
                    gr.DrawString(s, font, brush, x, y);
                    y += 0.33f;
                    dval -= 10.0;
                }

                // draw left axis value labels
                x1 = - 0.95f;
                y1 = - 0.65f;
                dval = 100.0;
                s = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    s = String.Format("{0:0.0}", dval);
                    if (i == 10) s = String.Format("   {0:0}", dval);
                    gr.DrawString(s, font, brush, x1, y1);
                    y1 += 0.33f;
                    dval -= 10.0;
                }

                // draw axes labels
                s = "Main Title";
                Pen drawPen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 0.01f);
                brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
                ff = new FontFamily("Arial");
                font = new Font(ff, 0.1f, FontStyle.Regular);
                gr.DrawString(s, font, brush, 0.65f, -0.85f);

                s = "X";
                font = new Font(ff, 0.08f, FontStyle.Regular);
                gr.DrawString(s, font, brush, 1.00f, 3.10f);

                s = "Y";
                gr.DrawString(s, font, brush, -0.95f, 1.00f);
                font.Dispose();
                brush.Dispose();
            }

        }// DrawGrid

        private void panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just make the panel a bit smaller and put the menu above it?

Comment: You only need ResizeRedraw = true if the form is doing any painting.  Assuming the strip controls are all docked to the top and bottom, just dock-fill the panel.  If it still obscures the strip controls, right mouse click the panel and select the SendToBack method.